# How do I get the start charms back on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

In windows 8, we had the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sjkC.png) start charms. We also had the option for the [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpJxG.jpg)start menu to have backgrounds (different from the desktop). [3 ]We also had the full screen list of programs.

Is there any way to revert to these 3 options?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sjkC.png) Start charms
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpJxG.jpg) Start Backgrounds
[image]
[3] Start full-screen application list
[image]

Edit: I don't need the list of programs to be full screen, but it would be useful.

Comment: You can't.  Charms were removed from Windows 10 in their entirety..  [How you enter Tablet mode in Windows is well documented.](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/27483d1438445073t-tablet-mode-turn-off-windows-10-a-tablet_mode_off.jpg) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/27482d1438445073t-tablet-mode-turn-off-windows-10-a-action_center_tablet_mode.jpg).  Of course the Tablet mode won't display your applications in an identical manner, full-screen application list, was basically removed.

Comment: Charms is no longer part of Windows 10 but someone created their own [PopCharms](http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-10-how-to-get-the-charms-bar-back-using-the-mouse). Tablet mode is close to the metro Start and Apps functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Its funny how people hated it earlier and now here we are . I still hate it though

Comment: Wouldn't even work with RTM more then likely.  Accept change has happen and move on

Comment: I didn't hate it, I used a touchscreen and it gave me a TOUCH feeling. Windows 10 feels like a small downgrade for touch. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Popcharms, an application that emulates the start charms. This is free to download. Also, if you are only looking for the functions of the pop charms for a certain application, then the top bar has three dots `...` with a list of commands that were used from the start charm.